# Select this or variable in function

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

The listenerForm() function is executed with addeventlistener. In the function I get the "this" object for get the dom element. Now I need use this function but I need pass the dom element in parameters. How to difference if I pass a parameter?

```
for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
 form[i].addEventListener("click", listenerForm,true);
}

function listenerForm(form) {

console.log(form); //result MouseEvent {isTrusted: true}
console.log(this);//result fomr element.

}

listenerForm(domElement);
```

If I execute function with addeventlistener, I only need get this. If I pass the form parameter, I only need parameter.
I found solution passing parameters in addeventlistener, but I can't create a function in for loop.

Comment: this, is nothing bus the current referenced object of the class in OOPS.

Comment: Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: i can't understand what you want to do by reading your question! but i think you want store `this` and use it as a parameter. so, try storing `this` in a variable and pass the variable name as a parameter in function and also pass it as a parameter where it's called!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using currying and the bind method is this

```
form.forEach(function(item){
  item.addEventListener('click', listenerForm.bind(null, item));
})
```

now the first argument of listenerForm is the element clicked and this refers to the global object

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need access to the event object (which it seems you don't?) then call the function from the event handler instead of using it as event handler:

```
form[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    listenerForm(this);
}, true);
```

Now the parameter `form` will always refer to the DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
 form[i].addEventListener("click", listenerForm(this), true);
}

function listenerForm(clickedFormElement) {
console.log(clickedFormElement);//result form element
}

listenerForm(clickedFormElement);// i don't know what you're trying to do here!!
```